# How can I fix a macOS screenshot of an X11 window that’s bleached / white / too light?

Tags: macos, catalina, screen-capture, x11

I'm facing a little problem while taking a screenshot of an X11 window
(using XQuartz - if there's something better out there, lemme know).

I tried everything:

- Entire Screen
- Window-Only
- Selection

Even tried recording the screen, same results - the box I need to screenshot (the one on the right) is always white:

[image]

(Side note: In the pic above the window is not "focused" (selected), but even with the "focus" on it, nothing change - even tried using the XQuartz setting where it focus the window on mouseover.)

This is how it should be:

[image]

Any idea on what setting I might need to change, in order to get my screenshot to work properly?

Oh... Almost forgot, I'm running the last macOS Catalina update (10.15.6)

Thanks in advance.

I might've found a solution by setting the Output as low as "256 Colors"

This the result

[image]

Edit: Added a pic of how it should be.
Edit 2: Added a possible solution.

Comment: Try `xwd` in an `xterm`.

Answer (score 3):

I use *xwd* to capture  a screenshot in xwd format, then display the screenshot using *xwud* and take a screenshot of the latter:

- place the X window on the main screen (it does not work for me on dual-screen setups)
- Open an XQuartz terminal window
- xwd -root -out screenshot.xwd
- xwud -in screenshot.xwd
- now take a regular screenshot of the xwd visualizer with any screen capture software

This system avoids the need for other tools to be installed and works directly with XQuartz.

Answer (score 2):

This looks to me like a display profile mismatch - specifically the gamut curve would do this.

Open your macOS system preferences and search for "profile"

[image: Display colors and calibration]

I would change these around a bit and see if you can get the images you want from the Screenshot app. Specifically, choosing a different display profile or running the [Display Calibrator Assistant](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/calibrate-your-display-mchlp1109/10.15/mac/10.15) to choose your specific values should help greatly.

If you’re sure macOS isn’t causing this, you’ll want to look at your Xorg or server preferences for color space if you need macOS to do the screen shots.

- https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/color/

Alternatively you might try [XScreenCapture](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xscreencapture/), `xwd`  or similar to capture the bits from X11 directly to an image file.

Comment: not works for me - screenshot colors still different that view colors

Comment: OK - now it’s on to using X tools if you’re isolated macOS as not the cause @KamilKiełczewski

Answer (score 1):

Go to Preferences under the XQuartz menu and then click on Output. You'll see a pulldown for colors.  Make sure its set to millions of colors. Then restart XQuartz.

Comment: Already tried that too, unfortunately same results...

Comment: not works for me too :(